# Doctrine2 getResult() duplicate objects

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a weird error in Doctrine 2
Repository function

```
$query = $this->_em->createQuery('SELECT c FROM \Model\Entity\Cluster c
                                  WHERE c.publisherid = :publisherid');
$query->setParameter("publisherid", (int)$publisher_id);
var_dump($query->getResult());
var_dump($query->getArrayResult());
```

And what we have

Objects:

```
array (size=8)
  0 => 
    object(Model\Entity\Cluster)[**396**]
      private 'psiteid' => int 215
      private 'psiteclusterdate' => 
        object(DateTime)[371]
          public 'date' => string '**2011-12-20** 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Moscow' (length=13)
      private 'publisherid' => int 276
      private 'views' => int 14657
      private 'clicks' => int 6220
      ...

  1 => 
    object(Model\Entity\Psitecluster)[**396**]
      private 'psiteid' => int 215
      private 'psiteclusterdate' => 
        object(DateTime)[371]
          public 'date' => string '**2011-12-20** 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Moscow' (length=13)
      private 'publisherid' => int 276
      private 'views' => int 14657
      private 'clicks' => int 6220
      ...
```

Rows with key 0-3 dublicate this object (396) and other rows dublicate second object.
When i dump as array:

```
array (size=8)
  0 => 
    array (size=22)
      'psiteid' => int 215
      'psiteclusterdate' => 
        object(DateTime)[367]
          public 'date' => string '**2011-12-20** 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Moscow' (length=13)
      'publisherid' => int 276
      'views' => int 14657
      'clicks' => int 6220
        ....

  1 => 
    array (size=22)
      'psiteid' => int 215
      'psiteclusterdate' => 
        object(DateTime)[396]
          public 'date' => string '2011-12-21 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Moscow' (length=13)
      'publisherid' => int 276
      'views' => int 10166
      'clicks' => int 4028
```

All the rows are different in array. What's wrong with objects?

Comment: I would examine the generated SQL $query->getSql();

Comment: SQL looks like `SELECT c0_.PSiteID AS PSiteID0, c0_.PSiteClusterDate AS PSiteClusterDate1, c0_.PublisherID AS PublisherID2,c0_.Views AS Views4, c0_.Clicks AS Clicks6, ... FROM Cluster c0_ WHERE c0_.PublisherID = ?` Returns a normal result, like in the array

Comment: the result is also duplicated?

Comment: No. Duplicating an object appears only as a result of the function getResult().  I don't have idea why it is happening =(

Comment: I should specify: getArrayResult() - return correctly result (array, where all rows unique). The same result is bring back a direct request to the database (query = getSQL()). Function getResult() return array, where the first four rows contain one object (and its links), and other rows contain second object (and its links). 
In the end, all the results contain 8 rows, but result from function getResult() contain only two object, other 6 rows contain links on this objects. Sorry for my English =)

Comment: I solved a problem. It is a bug in Doctrine2. I created bug report here http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1780 You can fix with in you project (if you can edit Doctrine library files). Just add  `if ($id[$fieldName] instanceof \DateTime) { $id[$fieldName] = $id[$fieldName]->getTimestamp(); }` in foreach loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved a problem. It is a bug in Doctrine2. I created bug report here http://doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1780

You can fix with in you project (if you can edit Doctrine library files). 
Just add

```
if ($id[$fieldName] instanceof \DateTime) { 
    $id[$fieldName] = $id[$fieldName]->getTimestamp(); 
}`
```

in foreach loop.